# Error my collectionview receives a list in the ItemSource and does not recognize the elements of that list

Tags: c#, maui

I have a Person object with properties of
Person{ string name; int number};
I built a form to send data to a Persons=list :

```
<Label Text="Name:"/>
             <Entry x:Name="labelName" Text="{Binding Person.Name}" Placeholder="Name"/>
             <Label Text="Nif:"/>
             <Entry x:Name="labelNumber" Text="{Binding Person.Number}" Placeholder="Number"/>
         <Button Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>
```

then I wanted to show this data below in a collectionview but an error does not appear:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
         <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                 </DataTemplate>
         </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
     </CollectionView>
```

Error " The Name "Name" don't exist in the current context"

I don't understand why it gives me the error I did everything correctly and by binding

After choosing ItemSsource={Binding Persons} it would be possible that the elements chosen below would be from Person element, that is, it should work <Label Text={Binding Name} but not working.

Comment: Please show more of your code. What do your models look like? Ideally include the namespaces.

Comment: Do you have this problem in debug or just in release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a [DataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings?view=net-maui-7.0)

```
xmlns:mynamespace="clr-namespace:MyNameSpaceForMyClass"
...
<DataTemplate x:DataType="mynamespace:Person">
```

you will need to specify the correct namespace using `xmlns`

Comment: Error "type 'local:Person' was not found. " what should i put in the xmlns?

Comment: the namespace for `Person`.  I have no idea what that is because you didn't post your code.